# The law of excluded middle in mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to make sure that I'm understanding this correctly.

Let ZFC denote the Zermelo-Frankel theory of sets with the axiom of choice. Let H denote the continuum hypothesis.

Let A be a formula of ZFC. Then (A or not A) is a theorem of ZFC. In particular, (H or not H) is a theorem of ZFC. However, neither H nor (not H) is a theorem of ZFC. That is, H is undecidable.

Is any of this incorrect?

Comment: Thats basically the shape of things.

Comment: The tacit assumption is that "this thing is undecidable" should always be followed by "unless ZFC is inconsistent".

Comment: A property that constructive logics typically have but classical logics lack is the [disjunction property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_and_existence_properties) which states that if $\varphi\lor\psi$ is provable, then either $\varphi$ or $\psi$ is provable.

Comment: To Sassatelli: ZFC is incomplete (not inconsistent), so there are undecidable statements, such as the continuum hypothesis. Consistency is also undecidable.

Comment: @herbsteinberg We don't know whether ZFC is consistent or not. If it is not consistent, then every statement is decidable albeit trivially. This is the point G. Sassatelli is making.

Comment: Let P be the statement "Randy Randerson likes cats". I can prove "P or not P" quite easily, but there's no way I'm going to be able to prove "P" or prove "not P" without knowing more about Randy Randerson than his math.stackexchange profile reveals. This is a totally natural state of affairs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, correct.

(Assuming ZFC) one can construct various *models* of ZFC.

For any closed formula $A$ and any model $M$ we either have $M\models A$ or $M\models \lnot A$. 
A formula is a theorem for ZFC iff every model of ZFC validates it.

Thus,  $A\lor\lnot A$ is indeed always a theorem, but for the continuum hypothesis, there are models that satisfy it and there are also which don't.

Comment: Assuming ZFC **is consistent** one can construct various models of ZFC.

Comment: The book I read doesn't use models. The theorems are just the provable statements.

Comment: @RandyRanderson Regardless of what book you're using, you should know about the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem). In general, the easiest way to prove that a given sentence is undecidable in a given theory is to construct a pair of models of the theory, one in which the sentence is true and one in which it is false. *(Actually, this really only uses the **soundness** part of the theorem, which states that everything provable from a theory is true in all models of that theory; still, you should be aware of the full completeness theorem.)*

Comment: Bourbaki didn't discuss this but I found it in another book. Isn't it true that a set is defined as a term in the first-order system ZFC? So ZFC is used to define interpretations of first-order systems, and then you can consider a model of ZFC, assuming that it is consistent?